# array positioning to generate report php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I have here is a list of item. Which is to filter fields to generate reports.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['report'])){

        if(empty($_POST['check_list'])){
            echo "Please select field!<br/>";    
        }

       if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){

        $id= array_reverse($_POST['check_list']);
        print_r($id);
         foreach($id as $key => $report_id){
            $s = $report_id . ',' . $s;
         }

          //echo $s;
         $xfields = substr($s, 0, strlen - 1);
         echo $xfields . ' was/were checked! <br/>';

         $x = substr_count($xfields, ',');

        echo '<table width=100% border=1>';
        echo '<tr>';
            $field_list = explode(',', $xfields);
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $x; $i++)
            {

                echo '<th>' . $field_list[$i] . '</th>';
            }


        echo '</tr>';
        $sql = 'select ' . $xfields . ' from areentry WHERE TagId = 1'  ; 
        //echo $sql;
        $rst = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$rst) {
            echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
            exit;
        }

        if (mysql_num_rows($rst) > 0) {

            while( $xrow =  mysql_fetch_array( $rst ) ) {
                echo '<tr>';
                for ($i = 0; $i <= $x; $i++)
                {
                    echo '<td>' . $xrow[$i] . '</td>';
                }  

            }
              echo '</tr>'; 
        }

        echo '</table>';

         return;
       }

    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo '<table border=1>';        
     echo '<ul>'.NL;
      while( $row =  mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ):
        echo '<tr><td><input type=checkbox name=check_list[] value=' . $row[0] . '>' . $row[0] . '</td></tr>';
      endwhile;
    echo '</table>';
    }
    ?>
```

the check box choices looks like this, after selecting field, it generate reports which have the fields that have check

[image]

How do i determine to what is the first item to get check ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$checked_list=$_POST['check_list'];

if(empty($checked_list){

   echo "Please select field!"; 

}else{

    for($i=0;$i<count($checked_list);$i++){

        echo $checked_list[$i]."Checked";

  }

}
```

Hope it Works....

Comment: thanks, it show only the item which has check, i need to know what box has got check first